# Mockito verification with timeout on synchronized method fails in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mockito, synchronized

When using Mockito `verify` with a timeout to wait for an asynchronous method call, it sometimes fails if the method is synchronized.

I have observed the effect with multiple versions of Eclipse, including 2020-06 (4.16.0), and both Mockito 3.1.0 and 3.4.6. The example below illustrates the problem (both the test and the subject under test are in the same class for simplicity). Why does this fail?

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class A {
  @Mock
  private A a;

  public synchronized void f() {
    // Do stuff
  }

  @Test
  void test() {
    // Call a.f() asynchronously and with a small delay 
    // (to make the test thread yield).
    new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
      } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
      a.f();
    }).start();

    // This verification fails, but it should pass.
    Mockito.verify(a, Mockito.timeout(2000)).f();
  }
}
```

Noteworthy points:

- The effect is not perfectly reproducible. In fact, my real-life examples never fail on some computers while they always fail on others, suggesting a race condition.
- Removing the `synchronized` keyword solves the issue, even when replacing it with a `synchronized(this)` block in the method body.
- If the class containing the synchronized method implements an interface, mocking the interface instead of the concrete class solves the issue.
- Removing the sleep in the example above, hence increasing the chance that the call to `f` is finished before `verify` is called, solves the issue.
- The behavior is suspiciously similar to the issue described (and presumably solved) here: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/253.

Comment: "it sometimes fails ... calls the real implementation". Does Mockito call the real implementation sometimes or always?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is hard to tell. On my machine (where the problem always occurs), the debugger always steps into the real implementation. However, there are machines where the test passes (at least my real-life test). This would imply that the mock method has been called as expected. Since I am not able to get it to work on my machine at all, I cannot debug that case.

Comment: Logging in the real method might help?

Comment: Ok, after trying again with my minimal example above, I found that it behaves differently than my real-life example in that it fails without calling the real method. So that answers the question.

Comment: And just for the record: reduce the number of variables when debugging such problems. As in: do it without an IDE. Just command line, javac, java binaries, text editor (it would very much surprise me if "eclipse" matters to this problem at all). And just for the record: try to write code that avoids raw threads. Use Executors instead ... as that can open to the door to use a "single threaded executor" in test environments. Which means: you can test your whole code, but run it in a single thread. Very often: good enough, yet deterministic.

Comment: As for not using an IDE:
My real-life example works when compiled with gradle and zulu java and fails in Eclipse. That is why I added the information. It might very well be a coincidence, though, since it works with Eclipse as well for others.
As for using raw threads:
I absolutely agree. In my real life-code the asynchronous call happens differently of course (and involves more classes). This was just an easy way to get an asynchronous call into a minimal example. Any asynchronous call with a delay will do here.

Comment: @PeterH any luck resolving this? I found your issue on github as well. I encountered the same problem using Mockito 3.4.6 and 2.28.2. I also presumed they resolved this from a similar issue. The only solution I have been able to implement is either reworking the synchronized method (remove synchronized method decorator) or make my test wait for async tasks to complete before verifying so that the verify call doesn't win the race and hold the lock on the mock that is being accessed asynchronously.

Comment: @Camputer Unfortunately, the issue still persists for me. I have indeed also raised it as an issue for Mockito on GitHub, but got no reply. My current workaround is to remove the synchronized keyword from the method declaration and use synchronized(this) in the method body instead.